# Why isn't this use of HashMap thread safe?

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap

I tried to circumvent concurrent `Node` collisions in HashMap by assigning threads to modify only their respective nodes. However, the expected size result is still not accurate.

I know HashMap cannot be concurrent because different threads modify the same linked list. `#hashSlot` is used to calculate the node inserted by HashMap.

Here is my example:

```
public class Maptest {

    private static HashMap map = new HashMap(1024,1);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread writeThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    int a = hashSlot(String.valueOf(i));
                    if (a >= 500) {
                        map.put(String.valueOf(i), i);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        writeThread.start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            int a = hashSlot(String.valueOf(i));
            if (a < 500) {
                map.put(String.valueOf(i), i);
            }
        }
        writeThread.join();
        System.out.println(map.size());
    }

    public static int hashSlot(String i) {
        int h;
        int b = (h = i.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
        return 1023 & b;
    }
}
```

The result is a map with `size() != 1000`, but none of the hash codes have collisions within the same thread. Why is it that the end size isn't 1000?

Comment: Thread-safety doesn't happen by default or by accident.  HashMap was not designed to be thread-safe, so it's not.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Comment: Because it [says so in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Comment: OP isn't looking for a concurrent hashmap implemention, he's wondering why his tailored case for hashmap which should be thread safe isn't. It's actually an interesting question once you dig down to the source, perhaps something conflicting with the views/parent class implementation, a cursory glance over hashmap seems like this would be safe.

Comment: To clarify further: he's using the same hashing algo as HashMap's internals, and attempting to only insert in two distinct groups of buckets (0-499, and 500-999). I haven't found the specific point of failure yet myself, but I enjoy a bit of concurrency masochism

Comment: Thank @Rogue  very much for helping me to revise the question grammar and answer my questions.

Comment: I'm very glad you understand my problem.

Comment: Not a problem, I enjoyed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some points regarding your current test case:

- On the initial map insertion, a call to #resize is made to construct the table. This isn't done in construction, so there's a potential race condition there.
- Continuing from above, I'd suspect that something akin to `map.entrySet().stream().count()` would return 999 or 1000, depending on if the race condition was hit.
- By using String keys instead of Integer keys, you're left to the #hashcode result of Strings, which is less predictable. You'll likely have a few items in the same bucket, but this shouldn't be too much of a problem since you're partitioning by the hash result. An Integer map may make crafting your puzzle a little easier

Now, in answering the specific question in regards to `size`:

```
//HashMap#putVal (near method end)
if (++size > threshold) //both are fields
    resize();
```

`threshold` is the size limit until the next #resize operation is called, which in your case is set to your `initialCapacity` argument: 1024. You'll never hit this in your test case.

*However*, `size` is just a preincrement at the end of the #put method, and it will always be called if you add a new value to the map. This is wildly thread unsafe, but overall wouldn't make a major impact on the functionality of the map to store and retrieve results. That said, don't expect `size` to really ever give a good value here, it'll only get worse the more you concurrently modify it. The real downside is it would throw off the map resizing calculations, deteriorating performance.

Comment: I probably understand your answer.I checked through debug and found that my calculated insertion point was the same as hashmap's final insertion point. Integer has the same problem as key. I think the problem should be write storage in different CPU caches. This caused overwriting by different threads writing

Comment: `/**
     * The array of bins. Lazily initialized upon first insertion.
     * Size is always a power of two. Accessed directly by iterators.
     */
    transient volatile Node<K,V>[] table;`Concurrent HashMap allows memory synchronization。But I changed the #map in my code to volatile, and the problem still exists.

Comment: `volatile` won't work in that way; it will make getting or setting the `map` variable itself atomic, but will not affect anything internally in the class. Much like a `final` Object can still have its contents modified. My point on the `Integer` keys was moreso you could do a `map.put(1023, 42);` to initialize the underlying table, while staying outside the bounds of both threads. Integer's hashcode is simply the Integer itself.

Comment: And ultimately yes, `++size` isn't an atomic operation; you have a memory read, an increment, and a memory write. Two threads can execute those at various points, so one may be writing while the other is still incrementing.

Comment: By the way, if the end result wasn't just tinkering but trying to learn making things thread safe, I'd recommend a venture into classes like `ReentrantLock`, `StampedLock`, using the `synchronized` keyword, and learning about atomic operations.

Comment: The first solution I tried was Integer. He doesn't work.I know Integer (n-1) & hash equals itself, but the problem doesn't seem to be here.

Comment: `And ultimately yes, ++size isn't an atomic operation; you have a memory read, an increment, and a memory write. Two threads can execute those at various points, so one may be writing while the other is still incrementing`I agree with that statement.

Comment: Thank you again for answering this question. Thanks very much.

Comment: Even if `++size` was an atomic operation, there is no guaranty that other threads see the updated value when doing their own update. And just to make that clear: the CPU cache is irrelevant. The Java specification makes no visibility guaranty, hence, the JIT compiler/HotSpot optimizer is entitled to emit code that simply doesn’t perform certain reads and writes, so architectures with coherent caches or no caches at all are still subject to such effects. Even on single core CPUs, such failures may materialize.